# PHP echo scraped input Value from HTML

Tags: php, html

I need to echo Values from input fields. Preferably **$var** name can be same as input fieldname. Sample: `echo $yesRedirect;` Should output: `No`

```
<?php
$html = array('<input type="text" name="yesRedirect" id="yesRedirectfunction" value="No">',
'<input type="text" name="noRedirect" id="noRedirectfunction" value="Yes">',
'<input type="text" name="quickcheck" id="quickcheckfunction" value="No">');

$result = array();

foreach ($html as $name) {
$dom = new DomDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($name);
var_dump($dom) . "\n";

//echo $dom->getAttribute('name') . "\n";
//echo $dom->getAttribute('value') . "\n";
}

echo $yesRedirect; // Should output: No
echo $noRedirect;  // Should output: Yes
?>
```

How can I simply echo input value? Is there any other way?
Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the results as wanted with this code below:

```
<?php

$html = array('<input type="text" name="yesRedirect" id="yesRedirectfunction" value="No">',
              '<input type="text" name="noRedirect" id="noRedirectfunction" value="Yes">',
              '<input type="text" name="quickcheck" id="quickcheckfunction" value="No">');

$result = array();

foreach ($html as $name) {
$name = str_replace('"','',$name);
$name = str_replace('>','',$name);

$varname = explode("name=", $name);
$arrname = explode(' ',trim($varname['1']));

$varvalue = explode("value=", $name);
$arrvalue = explode(' ',trim($varvalue['1']));

$result[$arrname[0]] = $arrvalue[0];

}

echo $result['yesRedirect'];
echo $result['noRedirect']; 
echo $result['quickcheck']; 
?>
```